# Convert date string to date epoch UNIX AIX

Tags: bash, date, unix, unix-timestamp, aix

I'm working with a AIX 5.3 version OS server, and I have to deploy a shell that I did in Linux (RedHat), but I have a big problem when I try to manipulate some timestamps.

In Linux I use:

```
`Start="Thu Mar 28 16:49:20 2019"` 
`date -d "$Start" +%s`
```

to calculate the seconds since 1970 that corresponds to the date, but in UNIX AIX 5.3 I get the following error:

```
date: Not a recognized flag: d
Usage: date [-u] [+"Field Descriptors"]
```

How can I do this in UNIX AIX? I need to calculate the seconds since 1970 from a specific date (date format: Fri Nov 25 02:11:53 2011)

Comment: Given the age of the OS (and the lack of updates that implies), I'm going to assume you have to work with what's already installed rather than installing GNU `date` yourself. What *is* installed? I think you are going to have to write your own implementation in a language that has access to the `strptime` system call.

Comment: According to the [man page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/date.htm), you can pass in a date in mmddHHMM[[YY]yy] format without any option; but it appears that this is only for *setting* the time.

Comment: @chepner I would like to do it in a native way, but the problem is the date function in AIX (like tripleee said).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert date to epoch on AIX with Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Usage: mkepoch yyyy mm dd HH MM SS

use Time::Local;
($yyyy, $mm, $dd, $HH, $MM, $SS)=@ARGV;
$tm=timelocal($SS, $MM, $HH, $dd, $mm - 1, $yyyy);
print "$tm\n";
```

Usage:

```
chmod u+x ./mkepoch
Start="2019 03 28 16 49 20"
./mkepoch $Start
```

Output:

```
1553788160
```

---

Source: [convert a specific date to unix timestamp](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/threadTopic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014802205)

Comment: Is there a way to do that with bash? My shell need to be with this interpreter. With perl I had problems to deploy my shell in production

Comment: `bash` simply does not have the ability to parse a date string by itself, nor does it provide an interface to `strptime`.

Comment: With perl -e I could execute perl commands, could I parse parameters from bash (in my shell) to perl (in my shell)?

Comment: I get some values and there are in my bash environment, I need this values (some dates) to parse to the pearl section. IE format dates: Fri Nov 25 02:11:53 2011

Comment: This might help as one-liner: `perl -e 'use Time::Local; ($yyyy, $mm, $dd, $HH, $MM, $SS)=@ARGV; $tm=timelocal($SS, $MM, $HH, $dd, $mm - 1, $yyyy); print "$tm\n";' 2019 03 28 16 49 20`